# How to write the right time to DB according my timezone?

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

When I save dates in my database Django shows message about succesfull adding with the right time but in fact in the databese time is different

[image: django admin timezone issue]

models.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models


class Teg1(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    num = models.FloatField(default=0.0, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num) + " || " + str(self.created_at)
```

settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Novosibirsk'
USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence of Django's [time zone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/) explains what you're seeing:

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

So the database value is in UTC. The `str()` value is also in UTC, since you've manually converted the UTC datetime to a string without changing the timezone. The value interpreted by the form and displayed by the template is in your local time, since templates convert `DateTimeFields` to the current timezone.

If you want the `str()` value to use the local timezone you can use Django's [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) function:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

class Teg1(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num) + " || " + str(localtime(self.created_at))
```

Answer (score 2):

If i'm not mistaken, you must be in Russia which is 7 hours ahead of UTC. So, the server that you use must be using the UTC time which in my opinion is a good thing.
I personally prefer to save times in UTC time in the data base and then convert them to the local time in the front end.

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

teg1 = Teg1(created_at=datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
teg1.save()
```

However, if you want to save the `datetime` in your local time, you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime    
import pytz

novosibirsk = pytz.timezone("Asia/Novosibirsk")
now = datetime.now(novosibirsk)
teg1 = Teg1(created_at=now)
teg1.save()
```

Have in mind that in your admin interface, you might see the time and date based on the timezone you select in your `settings.py`. However, the data saved in the database is still in `UTC` time.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
from datetime import datetime
class Teg1(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

use (this will use timezone that you have set in `settings.py`)

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Teg1(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime())
```